# Pop Up Window in VB.Net(aspx.vb) Code Behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have onclick button and when i debug,i found that my onclick value is NULL.Anyone Know why it cant get value for Onclick event.

```
Dim HTMLForm As New StringBuilder
HTMLForm.Append("<html>")
HTMLForm.AppendLine("<body onload='document.forms[""" & "form1" & """].submit()'>")
HTMLForm.AppendLine("<form id='form1' method='POST'>" )

'Set value to collection
SetRequestField("amount", CDec(lblTtlPayAmt.Text))

'Generate HTML content using collection
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In RequestFields
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Value) Then
        HTMLForm.AppendLine("<input type='hidden' id='" & kvp.Key & "' name='" & kvp.Key & "' value='" & kvp.Value & "' />")
    End If
Next

HTMLForm.AppendLine("<input type = 'submit' value=PayNow' onclick = '" & window.open("~/Payment/Payment.aspx") & "'/>")
HTMLForm.AppendLine("</form>")
HTMLForm.AppendLine("</body>")
HTMLForm.AppendLine("</html>")

Response.Clear()
Response.Write(HTMLForm.ToString())
```

Comment: Use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) to see some problems.

Comment: @AndrewMorton..Thank,bro.

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing `'` on the line which adds the submit button:

```
HTMLForm.AppendLine("<input type = 'submit' value=PayNow' ....
```

should be

```
HTMLForm.AppendLine("<input type = 'submit' value='PayNow' ....
```

Comment: thanks.But still cant work for pop up windows.I got try use the below method:
 HTMLForm.AppendLine("<form id='form1' method='POST' action =" & Page.ResolveUrl("~/Payment/Payment.aspx") & ">")
can i do like that? this above method i also try it.cant work.